# Как поместить выполнение методов в очередь?

Tags: java, android, очередь

Есть неплохой [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39132619/9189587), но не совсем понятно как методы добавляются в очередь, зачем нужен интерфейс MethodWrapper и как вообще вся эта конструкция работает

из ответа

```
public interface MethodWrapper {
void execute();
}

public class Potato extends Thread{
Queue<MethodWrapper> methodsQueue = new LinkedList<>();
public Potato(){}
run(){
       methodsQueue.poll().execute();
      }

//Methods of this class...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В коде все достаточно просто.

> зачем нужен интерфейс MethodWrapper

Этот интерфейс, как ясно из названия - обертка для метода, который добавляется в очередь.
Интерфейс нужно реализовать (как это делать смотрите ниже, где код) и в метод `execute()` добавить тело метода, который надо поместить в очередь.

> и как вообще вся эта конструкция работает

1. Создается очередь для объектов, реализующих интерфейс MethodWrapper.
2. `methodsQueue.poll()` возвращает первый элемент очереди и удаляет его, т. е. на выходе имеем объект, реализующий MethodWrapper.
3. В полученном MethodWrapper вызывается метод `execute()`, т. е. метод, помещенный в очередь. Интерфейс нужен был для того, чтобы этот метод выполнял код, который нужен именно вам.

Вот пример использования (взял ваш код за основу):

```
public interface MethodWrapper {
    void execute();
}

public class Potato extends Thread {
    Queue<MethodWrapper> methodsQueue = new LinkedList<>();

    public Potato () {
        methodsQueue.add(() -> {
            // Тело метода, который нужно поставить в очередь.
        });
    }

    public void run() {
       methodsQueue.poll().execute();
    }
}
```

Я использовал лямбда-функцию, но если вам нужен именно анонимный класс (для Java 7), то вот код:

```
methodsQueue.add(new MethodWrapper() {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // Тело метода
    }
});
```

Comment: Да, уже нашел что паттерн называется  Command, теперь вот думаю зачем он мне если есть лямбда-выражения. Вроде как последнее и  проще и ,мне кажется, менее ресурсозатратно.

Comment: Не уверен насчёт производительности, но улучшает читаемость кода.

Comment: Как раз про читабельность, - проще. Но вот зачем то этот паттерн появился(пишут-появился раньше лямбда-выражений) и используется в некоторых проектах(я нашел его использование в ThirtyInchMVP)...

Comment: Вот еще вопрос - как метод add() принял на вход лямбда-выражение, если оно вообще не относится к MethodWrapper?

Comment: MethodWrapper имеет один метод, так что можно использовать лямбду, это то же самое, что и анонимный класс, т.е. реализация интерфейса.